# WordPress and MySQL: how to transfer Meta_key and Meta_Value from one post_id to another

Tags: database, post-meta, mysql, sql

I have a lot of `meta_key` and their relative `meta_value` associated to a post, for example, `post_id = 4319`.

How can I assign, using an SQL query, all the values to another `post_id`? for example, `post_id = 6219`.

Comment: Can you please share details of what you've tried already? Example code is good, so are links to other posts.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET post_id = 6219 WHERE post_id = 4319
```

Comment: Thanks Otto. Your code works fine for me i need to transfer only some rows from post to post so i modified your query like this: UPDATE wp_postmeta SET post_id = 6219 WHERE post_id = 4319 AND `meta_key` LIKE '%foo%';